# Remote Locking

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, networking, protocols

I am designing a remote threading primitive protocol. Currently we only needs mutexes (i.e. Monitors) and semaphores. The main idea is that there doesn't need to be a central authority - the primitives should be orchestrated amongst the peers that are interested in them.

I have bashed a few ideas around on paper and in my head for a few weeks; but I think I should really have a look at prior literature. Is there any?

It will run over XMPP - but that is an implementation detail. I am just looking for a specification or such on the actual protocol flow - so it doesn't really matter what protocol the literature originates from.

Thanks a million.

Comment: not sure if this helps but i would have a look at the source of some of the open source middleware projects http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue , in particular there are quite a few higher level algorithm like distributed caches and the like that may use primitives like the ones you need and handle timeouts, corruption etc...

Comment: @sambo99 - why not make this an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributed mutexes are tricky structures. You need to handle all sort of weird conditions that do not exist with a single machine based implementation. In particular you need to handle situations where agents lose comms with the group and still hold a lock on a shared resource.   Additional to that scenario there are complex scenarios where your group is fractured and you grab a lock on a resource. When the fractured groups join into a big group you need some way to reconcile the locks which is far from trivial.

I would strongly recommend looking into some [messaging based middleware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) such as [Erlang](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-actor-concurrency1.html) and [JBoss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBoss_Messaging)

I would also recommend posting separate questions on the particular distributed algorithms / data structures you need implemented. It's possible that you could get away with an out-of-the-box implementation in a middleware library that could be adjusted to meet your needs.